# Count words between two tags as foreach

Tags: php, preg-replace

A post have some quotes. When a quote have more then X words, I have to display a error message. To count a string between two words I use this function / code:

```
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
    $string = ' ' . $string;
    $ini = strpos($string, $start);
    if ($ini == 0) return '';
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string, $ini, $len);
}

$fullstring = '<div class="quotecontent">This is the message with a lot of text</div>';

$parsed = get_string_between($fullstring, 'content">', '</div>');

$parsed_clean = strip_tags($parsed);

echo str_word_count($parsed_clean);
```

Now I have the amount of words inside of the quote.

**Problem:**

When the message have more then 1 quote, the function count only the words from the first quote and not from the others. How is it possible to count the text from every quote and display a error message with the text:

"*Please check your quotes. Minimum 1 Quote is longer then X Words*".

This shows the code in action.

http://ideone.com/PQAYUm

This shows the problem.

http://ideone.com/8bpnsq

Thank you.

Comment: Use `htmlentities()` before processing them?

Comment: Don't use ad hoc methods to process HTML, use a DOM parser library like `DOMDocument`. This will allow you to loop over all the elements matching a selector.

Comment: This approach is a _very_ bad idea. You are trying to parse html markup by means of string operations. Painful and error prone. Use a "DOM parser" instead: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have to run the code on a posting form before adding the text into the database. Can you give me a example?