# Use Jquery text().length inside of a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I found this usefull text counter by css class.

```
$(".quotecontent").filter(function() {
return $(this).text().length < 40;
}).parent().css('background', 'red');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/kh8Hh/

When arround the container is a textarea, the jquery code is not working anymore. Any Ideas?

See:

http://jsfiddle.net/e1j7xqsx/

thank you

Comment: Any content between a `<textarea></textarea>` is treated as it's value, so I'm not sure what you're expecting to happen in the second example

Comment: same behaviour as without textarea. My classes are inside the textarea and when a user make a fullquote (more then x words), I have to place a error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you examine the content of your textarea, you'll see that there is no DOM elements there:

```
    <textarea>
    &lt;div class="quote"&gt;
    &lt;div class="quotestart"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;div class="quotecontent"&gt;&lt;p&gt;We have a new toy!&lt;/p&gt;
    &lt;div class="author"&gt;- Fernando Alonso&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;div class="quoteend"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;/div&gt;

    &lt;div class="quote"&gt;
    &lt;div class="quotestart"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;div class="quotecontent"&gt;&lt;p&gt;Fight to fly, fly to fight, fight to win.&lt;/p&gt;
    &lt;div class="author"&gt;- Motto of the U.S. Navy Fighter Weapons School, TOPGUN&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;div class="quoteend"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;/div&gt;
    </textarea>
```

All the content inside textarea is text. So this `$(".quotecontent").length` is `0`.

One solution could be to have a separate DOM element acting as error containers, and you can show div's with errors there:

```
var errorWrapper = $('.error-wrapper');
errorWrapper.html($('textarea').text());

$(".quotecontent").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().length < 40;
}).parent().css('background', 'red');

$(".quotecontent").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().length > 40;
}).parent().remove();
```

Comment: thank you. That means there is NO solution for this problem? Maybe remove the textarea with replace or something?

Comment: what problem? why do you need `textarea` around `quote`'s?

Comment: There is a posting form. A forum user have the possibilty to quote a post. On submit I have to check the post from the user. When there is a quote with more then X words, I would like to place a error message: "Any quote is longer then X words, dont use fullquotes, remove some text etc."

Comment: update plunker with the form. does the use paste text into textarea?

Comment: well, its the normal forum quote behaviour. When there is a post and the user press the quote button, this post is in the submit form and the user have the possibilty to anwser to this quote. But some users do always fullquote long posts and this is a very bad way and I want to prevent this. Best way would be php for me, then I can check the $message but with php is maybe not possible, because nobody replied: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40513992/count-words-between-two-tags-as-foreach

Comment: thank you very much for your effort. I made a fiddle with your changes but I dont get it to work. Can you make a fiddle for this one? See
http://jsfiddle.net/q88L27mu/

Comment: @labu77, you have to add this wrapper into html like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/q88L27mu/1/)